# Java code to calculate electricity bill using conditional(ternary) operator?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

Here is the rate

```
0-20 units = 80 

21-30 units = 2

31-40 units = 3

41-50 units = 5

51 or above = per unit 10
```

Please help me I can't figure out how to solve this problem?

I can do this with if else statement but how to do with ternary operator? My teacher asked me to do this with ternary operator.

Comment: if or case statement...

Comment: What have you tried? Also, this doesn't seem like a good place for a ternary to me (since I believe you usually calculate the usage as a base plus some multiplier).

Comment: You should post some code that shows what you have tried, and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Best way is to use **else-if** ladder as java does not support **switch cases with ranges**
for e.g.

```
int units=0;
    if(units<20&&units>0){
        //do operation
    }else if(units<31&&units>20){
        //do operation
    }else if(units<41&&units>30){
        //do operation
    }else if(units<51&&units>40){
        //do operation
    }else{
        //do operation
    }
```

Comment: Groovy can do ranges in switch statements - not Java.

Comment: yeah wanted to improve your answer's quality

Answer (score 0):

Possible with some tenaries:

```
units < 21 ? 80 : units < 31 ? 2 : units < 41 ? 3 : units < 51 ? 5 : units * 10
```

but this really is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (units =< 20){
    rate = 80;
} else if(units =< 30){
    rate = 2;
} else if(units =< 40){
    rate = 3;
} else if(units =< 50){
    rate = 5;
} else {
    rate = 10;
}
```

If I understood the problem correctly then this will work, if this is not what you are after let me know and I can change this around.

Updated code using Ternary Operator

```
rate = (units <= 20) ? 80 : (units <= 30) ? 2 : (units <= 40) ? 3 : (units <= 50) ? 5 : 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add nested ternaries. That means that your code should look like this :

```
        int rate = (units >= 0 && units <= 20) ? 80 : (units >=21 && units <= 30) ? 2 : (units >=31 && units <= 40) ? 3 : (units >= 41 && units <=50) ? 5 : 10
```

but , as mentioned above , this is pretty ugly and hard to read. So, if you have the choice , make it with the else if pattern